# Bitwise OR and logical OR operators. What's the difference?

Tags: c

Is there any functional difference between logical and bitwise operators in the following code? What are the reasons to use one or another?

```
typedef unsigned char BOOLEAN;

void orOperatorsComparison(BOOLEAN bBar, BOOLEAN bFoo)
{
  BOOLEAN bLogicalOr = (bFoo || bBar);
  BOOLEAN bBitwiseOr = (bFoo | bBar);

  ...  
}
```

Comment: If `bBar` true, the variable `bFoo` is not even accessed....

Comment: does short circuiting only happen for the logcial operator?

Comment: thanks everyone, I hadn't thought of short circuiting, but that is exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: In particular, if `bBar` is some pointer derefence or some array access, it makes a big difference: coding `bFoo|bBar[20]` could crash when `bFoo`is true and `bBar` is not a valid pointer (e.g. is null, or too small array). But coding `bFoo||bBar[20]` would avoid the crash.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Then both operands wouldn't be a bool no longer, and the question would have yielded completely different answers.

Comment: @Lindin: You can declare `bool *bBar;` or `bool bBar[8];` .... and if writing `bFoo||bBar[10}` the second operand `bBar[10]` *is* a boolean....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That's far-fetched, though with that argument, bitwise OR is _better_, since it has a higher possibility of crashing the program, exposing the bug instead of hiding it away.

Comment: @ulidtko This is a C question and shouldn't be in a C++ FAQ. C++ has a true `bool` type and logic `||` expressions in C++ yield a result that is of type `bool`. In C they yield type `int`, because of implicit type promotions. I believe that the `|` operator yields an int in both languages though.

Comment: @Lundin Okay, point taken.

Comment: However, there still should be some kind of canonical formulation of this question, as well as its answer. I'd suggest making it happen right here.

Comment: hmmm this is only one tiny difference between the operators.

Comment: Recent C standards have `<stdbool.h>`....

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch But even in C11 there are no boolean _operations_. It is impossible to perform an operation in C and get a bool as result, you always get int. In C++, all the logical, relational and equality operators yield a true bool type. For example, `sizeof(A==B)` is 4 or similar in C, but 1 in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What does "support" mean?

If it's a logical or that you mean, then of course you should always use `||` since that is the Boolean, logical, "or" operator.

It has the benefit of being able to short-circuit, but that won't matter much in code this simple.

I would consider it odd and weird (and due for correcting) if bitwise or was being used when the point is not to manipulate bits.

Comment: support in this case means whether or not to make a stink in a code review. :)  I agree with you, I asked the question here to see if there were additional reasons other than it's odd and weird (which it is).

Comment: I'd suggest to make this question (and answers) a member of [C-faq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c-faq). Would you mind to cleanup the answer a bit?

Answer (score 8):

Other answers have already talked about short-circuiting (but that's not an issue in your particular code).  But here is one key difference.

If, for some reason, your input values are not in [0,1], then a bitwise OR will give you an answer that may also not be in [0,1].  Logical OR is **guaranteed** to give you 0 or 1.

For this reason, you should prefer logical OR.  Your intent is (presumably) to manipulate logical values, so using a non-logical operator is illogical.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* Pun definitely intended.</sub>

Answer (score 7):

The boolean || will short-circuit: if the first operand is `true`, the second will never be evaluated. In contrast, the bitwise | always evaluates both arguments.

Comment: but it wouldn't matter since both arguments are just simple plain unsigned chars

Comment: While this is true, you will not notice any difference on the machine code level. Any half-decent compiler will evaluate it into the same machine code.

Answer (score 3):

In that particular case, no, there is no difference in the *result*:

```
1 || 0 == 1
1 | 0  == 1
```

all the truth tables apply here.

If you're talking about how we *got* to the result then there *could* be a difference. With the `||` you have a short circuit mechanism:

```
BOOLEAN bFooBar = (bFoo||bBar) // if bFoo is TRUE, we never look at bBar
                               // vs
BOOLEAN bFooBar = (bFoo|bBar)  // where we take into account both values
```

So the long and short of it is, yes you can use logical and bitwise operators *incorrectly* in some instances and get the same results, but why would you ***ever*** do that? If you know it's wrong, and you know that it can lead to bad, hard to find bugs, use the tools the language gaves you for the jobs they were meant to do.

Answer (score 1):

The bitwise or operator never short-circuits while the logical one does. That is if `bFoo` is true, `bBar` is never evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any functional difference between logical and bitwise
>   operators in the following case?

Yes, there is (lazy eval as others have pointed out).

> Any reason to support one or the other?

If somehow they were equivalent, the case for using logical operators would be to preserve the semantic intended by the type.  See also: [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).