# Why does C have both logical and bitwise ‘or’ operators?

Tags: c, if-statement, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

Why C has both `||` and `|` operators? As far I know, `|` operator can replace `||` in conditions because it will return true (nonzero) value when at least one of operands is nonzero.

*I ask just out of my curiosity.* I know I should use `||` for logical expressions.

### Example

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int to_compare = 5;

    /* Try with bitwise or */
    if ((5 > to_compare) | (to_compare == 6)) {
        printf("‘to_compare’ is less than or equal to 5 or equal to 6.\n");
    }

    /* Try with logical or */
    if ((5 > to_compare) || (to_compare == 6)) {
        printf("‘to_compare’ is less than or equal to 5 or equal to 6.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `||` short-circuits, `|` doesn't.

Comment: One key difference is that with `||` it's guaranteed to be short-circuiting: that means if the first compare is true, it *knows* that it does not have to check the second one. A lot of code relies on this short-circuiting operation of `||` and `&&`

Comment: @EugeneSh. I thought `3 | 4` will be 7.

Comment: @jiwopene Woops. Meant `&/&&` of course. Edited, thanks

Comment: Actually `&/&&` do not apply to the question, removed

Comment: Logical and bitwise operators are a completely different thing, even if the symbolic portray of their respective operators might look very similar and one of your uses of them seems to providing nearly the same behavior/results. Find out more about each and you´ll find the difference very soon.

Comment: @RobertS-ReinstateMonica *I really know how to use logical and bitwise operators* but I ask *just for my curiosity*. I was just interested in the difference (if any) and I forgot short-circuiting.

Comment: @jiwopene I think the answers to that question, as well as the question itself, provide good answers for your concern also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29810766/what-is-the-difference-between-bitwise-and-logical-operators-inside-conditional

Comment: As well as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550966/bitwise-or-and-logical-or-operators-whats-the-difference

Comment: Furthermore, conditions like `(ptr | (i < 5))` would not even compile at all.

Answer (score 8):

`||` and `|` are very different beasts.

Aside from `||` having the short-circuting property (the right operand is only evaluted if the left one evaluates to 0), it's also a sequencing point.

The value of the expression can also be different: `1 || 2` for example is `1` whereas `1 | 2` is `3`.

(Note that `&&` and `&` have a more pernicious difference, for example `1 && 2` is `1` whereas `1 & 2` is `0`.)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the fact that the `||` operator is short-circuiting, the result of the `||` operator is always either `0` or `1` based on its truth, whereas the result of the bitwise or `|` operator will be a combination of bits that were set in the operands, which is not necessarily `1` (i.e. `0x0A | 0xB0 = 0xBA`, whereas `0x0A || 0xB0 = 1`.

**§6.5.14 Logical OR operator**

> The || operator shall yield 1 if either of its operands compare unequal to 0; otherwise, it yields 0. The result has type int.

**§6.5.12 Bitwise inclusive OR operator**

> The result of the | operator is the bitwise inclusive OR of the operands (that is, each bit in
>   the result is set if and only if at least one of the corresponding bits in the converted
>   operands is set).

Answer (score 1):

[In BCPL and B](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) -- C ancestors --, there is only `|` and `&`.  But their interpretation is dependent on the context: in control structures like `if`, they behaved like the C logical operators, in other contexts, they behaved like the C binary operators.  That was deemed too difficult to use and explain and thus additional operators where introduced so that the operator used indicated clearly if the operation was logical and short-circuiting, or binary and not short-circuiting.  And that also explains the inconvenient relative priorities with comparison operators.